# Linking excel/csv file to QGIS to update fields automatically using Macros

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am creating animated maps related to a couple of public health projects on Dengue and Zika. All our data is stored in Commcare, and then we can download it as an excel file, with all the data and headers (column titles).
So, if we need to create maps at any point, we have to simply export the data from commcare into excel, then convert that into a csv and join it to a shapefile of Iquitos called 'Noviembre_P01' (which contains the 'LOC_CODE' field on which is based the join with the 'loc_code' field in the csv file). The csv file is called 'project_2_gis_mapping'.

I want to automate this process of the attribute tables in qgis getting updated everytime I export this data from Commcare into excel as a csv file.

In the entire csv file, I have one column/field of interest - 'first_bloo'. I have created 1 additional column in my attribute table with this same name.

From my understanding, it seems that writing a Macros code will help me achieve this. Please can someone help with the Macros code for the same? Or, is there an easier/more efficient way of achieving this process?